# AppleScript: Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier for if block

Tags: if-statement, applescript, photoshop

I am trying to open Photoshop when my custom URL is typed in the browser

Following is the applescript am trying to compile

```
on open location this_URL
    if (this_URL contains "authenticate") then
        if application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2022" is running then
            tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2022"
                activate
                do javascript of file "/Applications/myApp/photoshop_open.jsx" with arguments {1, this_URL}
            end tell
        end if
    end if
    if (this_URL contains "default") then
        display alert "Files cannot be opened natively on the Mac"
    end if
    if (this_URL contains "photoshop") then
        tell application "Adobe Photoshop CC 2022"
            activate
            delay 2
            do javascript of file "/Applications/myApp/photoshop_open.jsx" with arguments {1, this_URL}
        end tell
    end if
    if (this_URL contains "illustrator") then
        display alert "Files cannot be opened in Illustrator on the Mac"
    end if
end open location
```

But i run into an error

```
error: Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier. (-2741)
```

The error points to

```
if (this_URL contains "photoshop") then
```

Have been trying to find solution to the issue for past 2 days.
Thanks in advance for suggestions and helps

Comment: The line you show is in itself syntactically correct, and the script compiles OMM so is syntactically correct as a whole. The only slight issue I found is that the Photoshop app’s name is normally “Adobe Photoshop 2022”, but assuming you’re editing the code in Script Editor/Script Debugger it should prompt you automatically to choose the app if it can’t find it itself. If it still doesn’t compile for you (strange), make a copy of the file and then commenting out/delete portions of the code till it does to narrow down the problem. It may also help if you can add a screenshot to your post.

Comment: @foo, thanks a lot for a very quick response. I was actually only changing the Adobe Photoshop's folder name to add CC to it (To maintain consistency with my other code) and never thought that could give me a syntax error.
thanks for pointing out in this direction and reconfirming the correctness of syntax.